# Laravel File Upload Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, mime-types

I'm new to Laravel. I have a form with a File upload function on it. How can I validate their file? I will only allowed Microsoft Word files. Here's my validation code.

I just want check if they insert a ms word file and if not it will not be processed.

```
public function store()
{
  // Validate
    $rules = array(
        'pda'                         => 'required|unique:forms',
        'controlnum'                  => 'required|unique:forms',
        'date'                        => 'required',
        'churchname'                  => 'required',
        'title'                       => 'required',
        'pastorname'                  => 'required',
        'contactnum'                  => 'required',
        'address'                     => 'required',
        'state'                       => 'required',
        'region'                      => 'required',
        'area'                        => 'required',
        'city'                        => 'required',
        'zipcode'                     => 'required|numeric|max:9999',
        'tgjteachertraining'          => 'required',
        'localcontact'                => 'required',
        'tgjdatestart'                => 'required',
        'tgjdateend'                  => 'required',
        'tgjcourse'                   => 'required|numeric',
        'childrengraduated'           => 'required|numeric|max:450',
        'childrenacceptjesus'         => 'required|numeric',
        'howmanycomitted'             => 'required|numeric',
        'recievedbibles'              => 'required|numeric',
        'descgradevent'               => 'required',
        'whatwillyoudo'               => 'required',
        'pastortest'                  => 'required',
        'teachertest'                 => 'required',
        'childrentest'                => 'required',
        'file'                        => 'required|max:10000',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('forms/create')->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        // store
        $forms = new Forms;
        $forms->pda                         = Input::get('pda');
        $forms->controlnum              = Input::get('controlnum');
        $forms->date                = Input::get('date');
        $forms->churchname                  = ucwords(Input::get('churchname'));
        $forms->title                       = ucwords(Input::get('title'));
        $forms->pastorname                  = ucwords(Input::get('pastorname'));
        $forms->address                     = Input::get('address');
        $forms->contactnum                  = Input::get('contactnum');
        $forms->state                       = Input::get('state2');
        $forms->region                      = Input::get('region2');
        $forms->area                        = Input::get('area2');
        $forms->citytown                    = Input::get('city2');
        $forms->zipcode                     = Input::get('zipcode');
        $forms->tgjteachertraining          = Input::get('tgjteachertraining');
        $forms->localcontact            = ucwords(Input::get('localcontact'));
        $forms->tgjdatestart            = Input::get('tgjdatestart');
        $forms->tgjdateend              = Input::get('tgjdateend');
        $forms->tgjcourse           = Input::get('tgjcourse');
        $forms->childrengraduated           = Input::get('childrengraduated');
        $forms->childrenacceptjesus     = Input::get('childrenacceptjesus');
        $forms->howmanycomitted         = Input::get('howmanycomitted');
        $forms->recievedbibles          = Input::get('recievedbibles');
        $forms->descgradevent           = Input::get('descgradevent');
        $forms->whatwillyoudo           = Input::get('whatwillyoudo');
        $forms->pastortest          = Input::get('pastortest');
        $forms->teachertest             = Input::get('teachertest');
        $forms->childrentest            = Input::get('childrentest');
        $file                   = Input::file('file');
        $filename                   = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
        $destinationPath                = 'uploads/'.Input::get('pda');
        $uploadSuccess              = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $forms->docurl              = 'uploads/'.Input::get('pda').'/'.$filename;
        if( $uploadSuccess ) {
        $forms->save();
        //Session::flash('message', 'Successfully submitted form!');
        return Redirect::to('forms/create'); 
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully submitted form!');

        } 
        else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To validate mime type of a file input in Laravel you can use the `mimes` rule. Remember to match the mime type detected with the actual mime of file you provide. It may vary on different servers.

For example, you want to enable adding and word document in you form:

1) in `config/mimes.php` add the below mime types:

```
    'doc'  => array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
    'docx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
```

2) in your validation `$rules` add the following elements:

```
    'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:doc,docx' //a required, max 10000kb, doc or docx file
```

Comment: yes, create it and filll similarily to the rest of config files, as an array of keys. As for the keys - that is what I included in my answer :)

Comment: Hi Thanks! I did what you said and follow this https://github.com/jasonlewis/laravel.com/blob/master/application/config/mimes.php

But I still got Error:

Comment: LogicException
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

Comment: well it seems you have your server underconfigurted, you are missing some extensions required for mime type detection ? What is your HTTP server stack and opearting system? By the way, if my answer solved your initial question, please accept it as official answer so others can also benefit when they encounter similar problems. Cheers!

Comment: Hi! I managed it to work. Thanks! I just forgot to enable some extension in my wamp server. Thanks! I give you a plus :)

Comment: @Gadoma why do a config and not use with `mimetypes`?

Answer (score 4):

As of [Laravel 9.22](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-9-22-0) you can write the validation rules a lot shorter and more readable like:

```php
'file' => ['required', File::types(['doc', 'docx'])->smallerThan(10000)]
```

You can find the available methods in this pr: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/43271

Comment: As of Laravel 10, `smallerThan()` seems to have been replaced by `min()` and `max()`. See [Laravel 10: File Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-files).

Answer (score 3):

Try this?

```
'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```

You may want to set some custom message for the response though :)