# Laravel: Importing CSV - validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, csv, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to validate a file that I want to insert in my db through a form. The file should be "csv" and its content to be validated as well.

Here is the import method in the controller that handles the form:

```
public function importFromCsv(array $data) {
    if (Input::hasFile('import_file')) {
        $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();

        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            //...
        })->get();

        $this->validator = new QuoteValidator();

        $this->validate($data);

        if (!empty($data) && $data->count()) {

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $insert[] = [
                    'content' => $value->content, 
                    'created_at' => $value->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $value->created_at
                ];
            }

            if (!empty($insert)) {
                DB::table('quotes')->insert($insert);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The validate method:

```
public function validate(array $data) {
    $this->validator = Validator::make($data, $this->rules, $this->messages);

    if ( $this->validator->fails() ) {
        $exception = new InvalidDataException();
        $errors = $this->_parseMessages();
        $exception->setErrors($errors);
        throw $exception;
        }
}
```

The error I got:

> ErrorException in QuoteService.php line 123: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Services\QuoteService::validate() must be of the type array,
>   object given, called in
>   /var/www/html/Acadia/app/Services/QuoteService.php on line 233 and
>   defined

Comment: Please ..post the code of your method `validate`. It is expecting receive an array. but `data` is the loaded Excel object

Comment: public function validate(array $data)
    {
          
        $this->validator = Validator::make($data, $this->rules, $this->messages);
        
        if( $this->validator->fails() ){
            $exception = new InvalidDataException();
            $errors = $this->_parseMessages();
            $exception->setErrors($errors);
            throw $exception;
        }
    }

Comment: i think the problem is you are trying to use a validator to validate the Excel object, but this validator expect to validate form fields.; Did you alread try this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625672/laravel-file-upload-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you are passing to the validate method is a Collection Object ([Documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#results)), but your validate method expects an array.

Before you pass the data to your validate method you have to convert it to an array. You could do that by calling the method `toArray()`

Example:

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
     //...
})->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Result: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Comment: in your if statement you are calling $data->count(). Now your data is an array. You have to change it to count($data).