# Upload Exception In Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

i want to created a custom uploader in laravel 5.2

i mean i want to ignore users to upload 'php files' in my file uploader

what can i do ??

this is my controller and method code:

```
public function workfreport(Request $request)
{

    $reportFile = $request->file('reportFile');

    if($reportFile == '')
    {

    }
    else {
        $reportFileName = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . "-" . rand() . "-" . $reportFile->getClientOriginalName();
        $reportFile->move('uploads/files/reports', $reportFileName);
    }

    $workreport = new WorkReport;
    $workreport->details = Input::get('detailsreport');
    if($reportFile == '')
    {

    }
    else {
        $workreport->reportfile_url = $reportFileName;
    }
    $workreport->reporter_id = Input::get('reporterid');
    $workreport->date = Input::get('reportDate');
    $workreport->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel File Upload Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625672/laravel-file-upload-validation)

Comment: @Metalik it doesn't helps me because i need to ignore php format

Comment: What is the exception error message that you get?

Comment: `reportFile->getClientOriginalName()` means I, the evil hacker, get to decide the generated file extension when stored on disk. It allows me, once again fully evil and everything, to upload my own php files. Those php files can be really evil.