# Why image validation accpet text file laravel postman?

Tags: laravel, api, file-upload, postman, laravel-validation

I am using laravel 8 and i am uploading file from postman. I have also write validation rules for png, jpeg and jpg. But when i select any other file its also upload it.
Form data in postman is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zdDv.png)

and my resource file for validation is

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'invoice_id' => ['required', 'string'],
        'invoice_date' => ['required', 'date'],
        'invoice_photo_url' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg'],
        'invoice_net_total' => ['required','regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/'],
    ];
}
```

and my controller method is

```
public function upload(InvoiceUploadRequest $request)
{
    try {
        return $this->responseWithSuccess(true,"Invoice successfully uploaded!",
            $this->invoiceInterface->uploadInvoice($request), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $this->responseWithError($exception->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

how can is solve this.
thanks

Comment: Pls post your controller method code in your question. And are you using a FormRequest class?

Comment: Yes i am using form request class

Comment: I have update question

Comment: Seems strange when using a FormRequest class validation is not getting evaluated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23625910/6793637    , i don't think individual field validation is supported for form data.  For file validation you can use the soultion mentioned