# "The file must be a file of type: png, jpg, jpeg, pdf, docx." error for valid files (PDF and PNG)

Tags: laravel, file, vuejs3

So, I am trying to upload a single file from vue3 to Laravel at backend. This is getting a validation error.

File type tried: PDF, PNG
Error: "The file must be a file of type: png, jpg, jpeg, pdf, docx."

The validation is currently:

`'file'=>'nullable|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,pdf,docx|max:2048',`

Front End:

```
formData.file = event.target.files[0];
```

If I console log my `formData`, it shows a file type object in `file`

Console Log Output:
[Console Log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jewSw.png)

But in Chrome Dev Tools, in the payload, I see file is an empty object.

```
file: {}
```

In the headers, there is

`"Content-type": "application/json; multipart/form-data",`

ALSO IT WORKS FINE ON POSTMAN!

I also tried

`'file'=>'nullable|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,application/pdf,docx|max:2048',`
`'file'=>'nullable|file|max:2048',`

Comment: Why multiple Content-type? [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809099/does-the-http-protocol-support-multiple-content-types-in-response-headers)
Please try with `"Content-type" : "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @linktoahref Thanks a lot, it worked! This is an ongoing project, where the other developer added both. We are importing the coded axios POST call from there. Need to check now if nothing else breaks after removing that part.

Comment: Created another custom method for multipart/form-data only. Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel File Upload Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625672/laravel-file-upload-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the 'nullable' rule if the file is required, I mean possible be input required and try change rules to

'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,pdf,docx|max:2048',

Comment: This is not required

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).